# Which element is the most frecuent according to a second table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, sql-like

I have two tables,

> phenotipos

```
id
GTEX-1117F
GTEX-ZE9C
K-562
```

and

> atributos

```
SAMPID
K-562-SM-26GMQ
K-562-SM-2AXTU
GTEX-1117F-0003-SM-58Q7G
GTEX-ZE9C-0006-SM-4WKG2
GTEX-ZE9C-0008-SM-4E3K6
GTEX-ZE9C-0011-R11a-SM-4WKGG
```

I need to know how many times each element from `fenotipos` It's in `atributos`
I tried to left join, but It doesn't work because the `id` aren't identicall to de `SAMPID`, and because `id` doesn't have the same number of characters each time I can either trim `SAMPID` with `(distinct left (SAMPID,x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join on a `like` condition, and then group by id and count:

```sql
SELECT   p.id, COUNT(*)
FROM     phenotipos p
JOIN     atributos a ON a.sampid LIKE CONCAT(p.id, '%')
GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated subquery a string functions to count how many attributes *start with* each phenotype:

```
select p.*,
    (select count(*) from atributos a where a.sampid like concat(p.id, '%')) as cnt
from phenotipos p
```

Comment: I was under the impression that mysql sucked at generating efficient plans for correlated sub-queries? Why not join and aggregate?

Comment: @MatBailie: I don't think correlated subqueries are inefficient in MySQL. In my experience, they even tend to perform better than join in such scenario, if you have the right index in place. Typically, the above query would take advantage of an index on `atributos(sampid)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your left join condition SAMPID rlike id:

```
SELECT p.id, sum(a.SAMPID is not null)
FROM phenotipos p
LEFT JOIN atributos a ON a.SAMPID rlike p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

This has the advantage of giving ids with 0 counts, plus it works no matter where in SAMPID id is located.

Comment: `COUNT(a.SAMPID)` would give the same result as your `SUM()`